# If $A$ is a connected subspace of $X$, can it be said that $Int(A)$ and $Bd(A)$ are connected? Is the reciprocal true?

Tags: general-topology

If $A$ is a connected subspace of $X$, can it be said that $Int(A)$ and $Bd(A)$ are connected? Is the reciprocal true?

Clearly the converse fails:

Take $A = \mathbb{Q}$, then $Bd (\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{R} $, and $ int(\mathbb{Q}) = \emptyset$ both are connected, but $\mathbb{Q} $ is not connected.

For the first question I have the following counterexample: Let $ A = [0,1] $, then $ Bd(A) = \{0,1 \} $ which is not connected. But I don't know anything about $ Int(A) $. Could you give me any suggestion for a clearer counterexample where $ A $ is connected, but not $ Int(A) $?.

Comment: You got an example (in the answers below) of connected set with disconnected interior. Here's an example of connected set with disconnected boundary: the infinite strip $[0, 1]\times \mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The boundary is $(\{0\} \times \Bbb R) \cup (\{1\} \times \Bbb R)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take two spheres that touch.  $ $

Comment: I wonder if there is any condition for that $Int(A)$ is connection. For example if $A$ is convex then it is true or not?

Comment: If $B$ and $C$ are in convex set $A$, then they are connected by the line between them.  If $B$ is in the interior, surrounded by a ball of radius $r$, then $xB+(1-x)C$ is surrounded by a ball of radius $xr$.

Answer (score 1):

EDITED: let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$

We can give a stronger counterexample; the implication that $\mathrm{Int}(A)$ or $\mathrm{Bd}(A)$ is connected doesn't hold.

Let
$$
    X = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus ( \{ (x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2; (x + 1)^2 + y^2 = 1, y \neq 0 \} \cup \{ (x, y) ∈ \mathbb{R}^2; (x - 1)^2 + y^2 = 1, y \neq 0 \} ) \text{ and}
$$
$$
    A = \{ (x, y) \in X ; (x + 1)^2 + y^2 \le 1 \} \cup \{ (x, y) \in X; (x - 1)^2 + y^2 \le 1 \} .
$$
Then $A$ is connected, but both
\begin{align}
    \mathrm{Int}(A) &= \{ (x, y) \in X; (x + 1)^2 + y^2 \lt 1 \} \cup \{ (x, y) \in X; (x - 1)^2 + y^2 \lt 1 \} \text{ and} \\
    \mathrm{Bd}(A) &= \{ (-2, 0), (0, 0), (2, 0) \}
\end{align}
are not connected.

Comment: The boundary will be two unit circles centered at (1, 0) and (-1, 0) which touch at the origin. So, the boundary is connected.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For the interior consider kissing spheres.  For the boundary consider a cylinder.